# Unable to locate element using appium inspector for iOS application

Tags: ios, appium, robotframework

[image]

As, you can see in the above snippet, when i try to locate value e.g.. '16' in this case or i would like to scroll to select any other value. I am unable to select or scroll from this window. Is it possible to select value using robot framework with appium library. suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can follow to do this is as follows:

1. First get the position of the element which is visible(In your case 16).
2. If you want to scroll down click on the element above 16 by substracting some pixels from the location you get in step 1.Verify for the element you want is highlighted or not.

Comment: Actually 16 can't be located as an element (as shown in XML hierarchy) or is there any way to locate the element whose xpath is not showing in XML hierarchy.

Comment: But you can use driver.findElement(By.id("16")); try once